# If two operators are related to each other by a unitary operator, are their eigenvalues the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue

If we consider 2 linearly independent basis as follow:
$$\{ |\psi_1 \rangle  , |\psi_2 \rangle ... |\psi_n \rangle\}$$
$$\{ |\phi_1 \rangle  , |\phi_2 \rangle ... |\phi_n \rangle\}$$

And they are related by a unitary tranform such that:
$$U|\psi_i\rangle = |\phi_n\rangle$$

If O is an oprator in basis $\{ |\psi_1 \rangle  , |\psi_2 \rangle ... |\psi_n \rangle\}$ and O' is operator in basis $\{ |\phi_1 \rangle  , |\phi_2 \rangle ... |\phi_n \rangle\}$, and we could write the spectral decomposition as follows:

$$O = \sum_n \lambda_n |\psi_n \rangle \langle\psi_n|$$
$$O' = \sum_n \mu_n |\phi_n \rangle \langle\phi_n|$$

Would it be true to say that the eigenvalues $\mu_n$ and $\lambda_n$ are equal to one another?

Comment: Hi! What do you think about this? Please share the concepts you are thinking about. Also, are $O$ and $O'$ the same operator in two different bases? Or are they two different operators?

Comment: Well the problem I am trying to solve doesn't explicitly mention whether it is the same operator in a different basis however I suspect the relationship that $U|\psi_i\rangle = |\phi_n\rangle$ would suggest that is probably the case.  In which case,  if I had to guess I would say that the eigenvalues probably are the same since obviously  a measured observable would be the same independent of the basis that the operator is represented in.

Comment: Your guess is obviously right:  take $O''$ diagonal in the same basis as $O'$, but with different eigenvalues $\mu_n''$ than $O'$. So, now $\lambda_n$ cannot be both equal to $\mu_n$ and $\mu_n''$. It is equal to the respective eigenvalue of the unitarily equivalent operator $O'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given that
$$U|\psi_n\rangle = |\phi_n\rangle$$
where $U$ is a unitary matrix and $|\psi_n\rangle$ are eigenkets of $\hat{O}$ and $|\phi_n\rangle$ are eigenkets of $\hat{O'}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and $\mu_n$, respectively.

Equivalently,
$$|\psi_n\rangle = U^\dagger|\phi_n\rangle$$

Since $\hat{O'}|\phi_n\rangle = \mu_n|\phi_n\rangle$ and $\hat{O}|\psi_n\rangle = \lambda_n |\psi_n\rangle$, and since $\hat{O'} = (U\hat{O}U^\dagger)$, then

$$ \mu_n|\phi_n\rangle = \hat{O'}|\phi_n\rangle = \hat{O'} U|\psi_n\rangle = (U\hat{O}U^\dagger)U|\psi_n\rangle = U\hat{O}|\psi_n\rangle = U\lambda_n|\psi_n\rangle = \lambda_n U|\psi_n\rangle = \lambda_n |\phi_n\rangle$$

Thus, $\lambda_n = \mu_n$ and they share the same eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean that, since $\langle \psi_n|U^\dagger =\langle \phi_n|$,
$$ O'=UOU^\dagger = \sum_n \lambda_n U|\psi_n \rangle \langle\psi_n| U^\dagger=  \sum_n \lambda_n |\phi_n \rangle \langle\phi_n|=   
 O'  ,$$   unitarily equivalent.

So, if $O$ and $O'$ are unitarily equivalent, the corresponding transformation of their eigenstate decompositions forces $\lambda_n=\mu_n$.

If they are not unitarily equivalent, the eigenvalues won't coincide: any operator can be written in any unitarily equivalent basis, and the basis by itself cannot tell it what it is or isn't!

Try a 2x2 matrix example. Note the trace and determinant of two unitarily equivalent matrices coincide.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: I don't see how your last equality follows.

Comment: The question title.

Comment: @DJA perhaps you'll find my proof a bit more clear, but also more rote. :)

Comment: @DJA sorry there was bad typos in the first version of my answer. Fixed now though.